# select one column using multiple like statement in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I am using php pdo and mysql, i want to select one more column using like statement. currently i have this query. And this query work fine.

```
$get_name = $db->prepare("SELECT dou.businessName, m.ownerid FROM dineOwnerUser AS dou INNER JOIN menu AS m ON dou.id = m.ownerid WHERE
(m.firstFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.secondFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.thirdFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.fourthFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.fifthFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.sixthFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.seventhFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.eightFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.ninthFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.tenthFood LIKE '%$text%')");
```

As you can see right now i am getting only business name and owner id by the help of food column. Now i want to select exact column which user enters but i dont know how to sort that exact column and select that from several columns i tried this.

```
SELECT dou.businessName , m.ownerid,
(m.firstFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.secondFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.thirdFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.fourthFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.fifthFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.sixthFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.seventhFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.eightFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.ninthFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.tenthFood LIKE '%$text%') FROM dineOwnerUser AS dou INNER JOIN menu AS m ON m.ownerid = dou.id WHERE
(m.firstFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.secondFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.thirdFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.fourthFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.fifthFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.sixthFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.seventhFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.eightFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.ninthFood LIKE '%$text%'
OR m.tenthFood LIKE '%$text%')
```

but it does not select required column.
NOTE: "%text%" is coming from form input field and every thing working perfect i just need correct mysql query.

EDITED: basically i want to select exact food column let say user enters b and biryani is in column "secondFood" so i want to select that column along businessName and m.ownerid.

Comment: numbered food columns? have you missed an opportunity to create a new table, maybe with a number column, and join on it.

Comment: dineOwnerUser's id is fk in menu table with the name of ownerid(it is coming from dineOwnerUser table)

Comment: {first,second,third....tenth}food - seems like there should be a `food( item VARCHAR, num UNSIGNED INT)` table instead of it all being in the menu table.

Comment: this is menu table
# Name Type Collation Attributes Null Default Comments Extra
1 idPrimary int(11)  UNSIGNED No None  AUTO_INCREMENT
2 firstFood varchar(30) utf8mb4_unicode_ci  Yes NULL  
3 priceone varchar(10) utf8mb4_unicode_ci  Yes NULL  
4 secondFood varchar(30) utf8mb4_unicode_ci  Yes NULL

Comment: this is dineowneruser table.
# Name Type Collation Attributes Null Default Comments Extra
1 idPrimary int(11)   No None  AUTO_INCREMENT
2 firstName varchar(25) utf8mb4_unicode_ci  No None  
3 lastName varchar(25) utf8mb4_unicode_ci  No None  
4 email varchar(60) utf8mb4_unicode_ci  No None  
5 password varchar(255) utf8mb4_unicode_ci  No None  
6 businessName varchar(70) utf8mb4_unicode_ci  No None

Comment: What @danblack is getting at is [database normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) - its a concept to get familiar with when designing tables.

Comment: yes. getting table structure sane leads to good queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to select specific column via word, for example user type p and pasta is in column named m.tenthFood then you want the value of this column and show it to your website if you think this it is impossible because in subquery multiple columns (result) cant come so your query fails here. As you said you are using php pdo thats mean you are showing this value somewhere so you have to select all columns and then do some logic to remove the null or empty columns then show only that columns which have pasta, pori, panir and so on. To do this you need this query.

```
    SELECT dou.businessName , m.ownerid, IF (m.firstFood LIKE '%r%', m.firstFood, "no")
, IF (m.secondFood LIKE '%r%', m.secondFood, "no")
, IF (m.thirdFood LIKE '%r%', m.thirdFood, "no")
, IF (m.fourthFood LIKE '%r%', m.fourthFood, "no")
, IF (m.fifthFood LIKE '%r%', m.fifthFood, "no")
, IF (m.sixthFood LIKE '%r%', m.sixthFood, "no")
, IF (m.seventhFood LIKE '%r%', m.seventhFood, "no")
, IF (m.eightFood LIKE '%r%', m.eightFood, "no")
, IF (m.ninthFood LIKE '%r%', m.ninthFood, "no")
, IF (m.tenthFood LIKE '%r%', m.tenthFood, "no")
FROM dineOwnerUser AS dou INNER JOIN menu AS m ON m.ownerid = dou.id WHERE
(m.firstFood LIKE '%r%'
OR m.secondFood LIKE '%r%'
OR m.thirdFood LIKE '%r%'
OR m.fourthFood LIKE '%r%'
OR m.fifthFood LIKE '%r%'
OR m.sixthFood LIKE '%r%'
OR m.seventhFood LIKE '%r%'
OR m.eightFood LIKE '%r%'
OR m.ninthFood LIKE '%r%'
OR m.tenthFood LIKE '%r%')
```

Explanation:
AFTER WHERE clause it is called subquery and it will return only one answer (in common language) so you are checking which column has some thing which contain "P" then you are taking ownerid and business name and all food columns. In upper part which contain IF statement it will return colum's value if it does not contain it will return "no". By using conditions you can neglect those column and show only right columns which you need such as pasta, panir.....
I hope this will work for you.
Cheersss

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the select using IF or CASE but the query can be ugly

```
IF (m.firstFood IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('firstFood:', m.firstFood), 
  IF (m.secondFood IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('secondFood:', m.secondFood),
    IF (m.thirdFood IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('thirdFood:', m.thirdFood),
      IF (m.fourthFood IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('fourthFood :', m.fourthFood ),
...................................
)))) as thirdColumn
```